# USB to Ethernet device not working

Tags: networking, usb

I have [USB 3.0 to Gigabit Ethernet Adapter](https://www.trendnet.com/support/supportdetail.asp?prod=315_TU3-ETG). I'm trying to get working on Ubuntu 18.04

```
$ lsusb 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0b95:1790 ASIX Electronics Corp. AX88179 Gigabit Ethernet
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0eef:c0aa D-WAV Scientific Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:58c6 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hu

$ ifconfig
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 1904  bytes 206432 (206.4 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1904  bytes 206432 (206.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp1s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.126  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::5b52:8606:7116:4b51  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 70:1c:e7:75:7e:cf  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 12058  bytes 10801854 (10.8 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 8521  bytes 1601052 (1.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
rfcomm                 77824  4
ccm                    20480  6
pci_stub               16384  1
vboxpci                24576  0
vboxnetadp             28672  0
vboxnetflt             28672  0
vboxdrv               471040  3 vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt,vboxpci
bnep                   20480  2
binfmt_misc            20480  1
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     49152  1
snd_soc_skl            90112  0
snd_soc_skl_ipc        65536  1 snd_soc_skl
snd_hda_ext_core       24576  1 snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_sst_dsp        32768  1 snd_soc_skl_ipc
snd_soc_sst_ipc        16384  1 snd_soc_skl_ipc
snd_soc_acpi           16384  1 snd_soc_skl
snd_hda_codec_realtek   106496  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    73728  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_soc_core          241664  1 snd_soc_skl
snd_compress           20480  1 snd_soc_core
ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_hda_intel          40960  6
snd_hda_codec         126976  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
arc4                   16384  2
dell_laptop            20480  1
dell_smbios_smm        16384  0
dcdbas                 16384  1 dell_smbios_smm
snd_hda_core           81920  7 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_soc_skl,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
dell_smm_hwmon         16384  0
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
intel_rapl             20480  0
btusb                  45056  0
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
intel_powerclamp       16384  0
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
coretemp               16384  0
uvcvideo               86016  0
snd_pcm                98304  8 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_pcm_dmaengine,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_core,snd_soc_skl,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_soc_core
btintel                16384  1 btusb
bluetooth             548864  33 btrtl,btintel,bnep,btbcm,rfcomm,btusb
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
kvm_intel             212992  0
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
ax88179_178a           24576  0
iwlmvm                364544  0
videobuf2_v4l2         24576  1 uvcvideo
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
videobuf2_core         40960  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_v4l2
usbnet                 45056  1 ax88179_178a
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
mii                    16384  2 usbnet,ax88179_178a
hid_multitouch         20480  0
kvm                   598016  1 kvm_intel
ecdh_generic           24576  1 bluetooth
videodev              184320  3 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2
mac80211              778240  1 iwlmvm
media                  40960  2 uvcvideo,videodev
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                65536  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
intel_cstate           20480  0
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
iwlwifi               282624  1 iwlmvm
intel_rapl_perf        16384  0
dell_smbios_wmi        16384  0
dell_wmi               16384  0
snd                    81920  25 snd_compress,snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_seq,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm
input_leds             16384  0
joydev                 24576  0
dell_smbios            16384  4 dell_wmi,dell_laptop,dell_smbios_wmi,dell_smbios_smm
cfg80211              622592  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
wmi_bmof               16384  0
dell_wmi_descriptor    16384  2 dell_wmi,dell_smbios_wmi
hid_sensor_incl_3d     16384  0
serio_raw              16384  0
soundcore              16384  1 snd
hid_sensor_gyro_3d     16384  0
hid_sensor_rotation    16384  0
hid_sensor_magn_3d     16384  1
hid_sensor_accel_3d    16384  1
hid_sensor_trigger     16384  11 hid_sensor_incl_3d,hid_sensor_accel_3d,hid_sensor_magn_3d,hid_sensor_gyro_3d,hid_sensor_rotation
industrialio_triggered_buffer    16384  5 hid_sensor_incl_3d,hid_sensor_accel_3d,hid_sensor_magn_3d,hid_sensor_gyro_3d,hid_sensor_rotation
kfifo_buf              16384  1 industrialio_triggered_buffer
hid_sensor_iio_common    16384  6 hid_sensor_incl_3d,hid_sensor_accel_3d,hid_sensor_trigger,hid_sensor_magn_3d,hid_sensor_gyro_3d,hid_sensor_rotation
industrialio           69632  10 hid_sensor_incl_3d,hid_sensor_accel_3d,hid_sensor_trigger,hid_sensor_magn_3d,hid_sensor_gyro_3d,hid_sensor_rotation,industrialio_triggered_buffer,kfifo_buf
idma64                 20480  0
virt_dma               16384  1 idma64
intel_vbtn             16384  0
soc_button_array       16384  0
int3403_thermal        16384  0
processor_thermal_device    16384  0
intel_lpss_pci         20480  0
mei_me                 40960  0
int3402_thermal        16384  0
mei                    90112  1 mei_me
int340x_thermal_zone    16384  3 int3402_thermal,int3403_thermal,processor_thermal_device
shpchp                 36864  0
intel_pch_thermal      16384  0
intel_soc_dts_iosf     16384  1 processor_thermal_device
intel_lpss             16384  1 intel_lpss_pci
intel_hid              16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  3 dell_wmi,intel_hid,intel_vbtn
int3400_thermal        16384  0
acpi_thermal_rel       16384  1 int3400_thermal
acpi_pad              180224  0
mac_hid                16384  0
sch_fq_codel           20480  5
parport_pc             36864  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,parport_pc,ppdev
ip_tables              28672  0
x_tables               40960  1 ip_tables
autofs4                40960  2
algif_skcipher         16384  0
af_alg                 24576  1 algif_skcipher
dm_crypt               40960  2
hid_sensor_custom      20480  0
hid_sensor_hub         20480  8 hid_sensor_incl_3d,hid_sensor_accel_3d,hid_sensor_iio_common,hid_sensor_trigger,hid_sensor_magn_3d,hid_sensor_gyro_3d,hid_sensor_rotation,hid_sensor_custom
intel_ishtp_hid        20480  0
usbhid                 49152  0
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
pcbc                   16384  0
i915                 1617920  29
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
drm_kms_helper        172032  1 i915
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
aesni_intel           188416  8
intel_ish_ipc          20480  0
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
ahci                   36864  3
cryptd                 24576  5 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel
psmouse               147456  0
intel_ishtp            40960  2 intel_ishtp_hid,intel_ish_ipc
drm                   401408  16 i915,drm_kms_helper
libahci                32768  1 ahci
i2c_hid                20480  0
wmi                    24576  4 dell_wmi,wmi_bmof,dell_wmi_descriptor,dell_smbios_wmi
hid                   118784  5 hid_sensor_hub,i2c_hid,usbhid,hid_multitouch,intel_ishtp_hid
video                  45056  3 dell_wmi,dell_laptop,i915
pinctrl_sunrisepoint    28672  0
```

Any advice? My wifi works fine if btw.

Comment: There is a driver in the link you mentioned. did you tried that?

Comment: I downloaded it and then did `make` and `make install` then `modprobe usbnet` and `sudo insmod ax88179_178a.ko 
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module ax88179_178a.ko: File exists`

Comment: What does `modprobe` show?

Comment: And try removing the module before inserting a new version.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what commands to run? `modprobe` returns missing parameters. `modprobe usbnet` doesn't return anything it just goes to the next line after executing. How do I remove the module?

Comment: try `lsmod` to see module's statuses, and check the man pages for other useful sounding commands like modinfo, rmmod, etc

Answer (score 5):

I'm sorry but it seems that driver for your device is already [included into the Linux kernel](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=ax88179).

On my Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS with 4.15 kernel I have the following output of `modinfo ax88179_178a`:

```
$ modinfo ax88179_178a
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-33-generic/kernel/drivers/net/usb/ax88179_178a.ko
license:        GPL
description:    ASIX AX88179/178A based USB 3.0/2.0 Gigabit Ethernet Devices
srcversion:     5198353D2D0B5A7C431BB10
alias:          usb:v050Dp0128d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v17EFp304Bd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v04E8pA100d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p0072d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2001p4A00d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v04B4p3610d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0B95p178Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0B95p1790d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in* <--- yours VID and PID!
depends:        usbnet,mii
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           ax88179_178a
vermagic:       4.15.0-33-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
```

The driver may be installed with

```
sudo apt-get install linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)
```

---

If you want - you can use the driver, provided by Trendnet:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://downloads.trendnet.com/tu3-etg/utilities/linux_tu3-etg.zip
unzip linux_tu3-etg.zip
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe usbnet
sudo insmod ax88179_178a.ko
```

If it does not work then remove Trendnet's driver with:

```
sudo rm /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net/usb/ax88179_178a.ko
sudo /sbin/depmod -a
```

and reinstall kernel modules package from repositories with

```
sudo apt-get install linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) --reinstall
```

---

Note: just tested D-Link DUB-1312 (2001:4a00), it works out the box even on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with Linux 4.4 using preinstalled kernel module `ax88179_178a`:

```
$ cat /var/log/syslog | grep kernel
Sep 21 22:07:46 hostname kernel: [  767.258696] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
Sep 21 22:07:46 hostname kernel: [  767.281700] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=2001, idProduct=4a00
Sep 21 22:07:46 hostname kernel: [  767.281707] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Sep 21 22:07:46 hostname kernel: [  767.281712] usb 4-1: Product: D-Link DUB-1312
Sep 21 22:07:46 hostname kernel: [  767.281716] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: D-Link Elec. Corp.
Sep 21 22:07:46 hostname kernel: [  767.281719] usb 4-1: SerialNumber: 000000000015B6
Sep 21 22:07:47 hostname kernel: [  767.608195] ax88179_178a 4-1:1.0 eth0: register 'ax88179_178a' at usb-0000:00:14.0-1, D-Link DUB-1312 USB 3.0 to Gigabit Ethernet Adapter, 18:0f:76:xx:xx:xx

$ lsusb -d 2001:4a00
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 2001:4a00 D-Link Corp.

$ lsmod | grep ax88179_178a
ax88179_178a           24576  0
usbnet                 45056  1 ax88179_178a
mii                    16384  2 usbnet,ax88179_178a
```

Comment: I think I already have it installed. `~$ sudo apt-get install linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-34-generic is already the newest version (4.15.0-34.37).
linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-34-generic set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 37 not upgraded.` Is there something I need to do after plugging in the device and the ethernet? Nothing happens and my computer just stays on wifi. If I turn off wifi it goes into airplane mode.

Comment: Usually the sequence is the following: device inserted, udev detected it and kernel driver loaded (you can check `/var/log/syslog` entries and `lsmod | grep ax88179_178a`), ethernet interface created (check with `ifconfig -a`) and shown in NetworkManager (check with `nmcli device`), then if cable is connected it will obtain address from DHCP-server.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same laptop as OP with Ubuntu 18.04, and the same problem. For me, a workaround was to unplug/replug the usb ethernet dongle WITHOUT having the ethernet cable plugged into the dongle. After that, `lsusb` shows my device as:

```
Bus 002 Device 025: ID 0bda:8153 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
Bus 002 Device 024: ID 05e3:0616 Genesys Logic, Inc. hub
```

After this, the ethernet cable can be replugged. I already had dhcp ready on the router side, so at this point the ethernet comes up and is properly connected (check with "ip address show").

Note: My ethernet usb dongle hardware is probably different from OP, but the workaround is worth a try.

Is it a bug that the usb ethernet device will not start properly when the ethernet cable is plugged in before plugging the usb side of the device? It seems like incorrect behavior to me.