# Cannot connect to Internet over Ethernet

Tags: networking, drivers, updates, internet, ethernet

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 from 18.04, and my Ethernet connection is not working. When I was using 18.04 everything was working fine, but since the upgrade I can't get a wired connection to work although WiFi works fine. My laptop doesn't have any Ethernet ports, so I have an adapter (link below) that I've used for a few years. I didn't see any drivers and they even said drivers aren't necessary for Linux for the adapter. I found some pages saying to go to the Network tab in settings, but I only have options to set up a VPN (screenshot link below).

USB-Ethernet adapter: https://en.j5create.com/products/jue130

[image: Network Settings Screenshot]

Results of `lsusb` :

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0b95:1790 ASIX Electronics Corp. AX88179 Gigabit Ethernet
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 03eb:8ab3 Atmel Corp. Atmel maXTouch Digitizer
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04f2:b59c Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: It's a little difficult to read so I'll add an edit to the original post.

$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0b95:1790 ASIX Electronics Corp. AX88179 Gigabit Ethernet
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 03eb:8ab3 Atmel Corp. Atmel maXTouch Digitizer
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04f2:b59c Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Comment: Same exact question with the same exact hardware two years ago: [USB to Ethernet device not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1076800/usb-to-ethernet-device-not-working). Take a look at the easy answers first, like plugging in the USB dongle *without* ethernet plugged in, before moving to harder answers. You should not need to compile a kernel module (driver).